# Linking SFML statically using cmake

Tags: cmake, sfml

I have the problem with linking SFML library statically, but dynamically it works. What is wrong here?

Here is how I fetch SFML by downloading it online.

```
# Fetch sfml library
FetchContent_Declare(
    sfml
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/SFML/SFML.git
)
# set(SFML_STATIC_LIBRARIES TRUE)  # I bet it should be true, but it's not working, see at the bottom
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(sfml)
```

and here is the linking command

```
#linking libraries
target_link_libraries(ProgramName sfml-graphics sfml-window sfml-system ...)
```

I bet there should be suffixes '-s' added to each (e.g. sfml-window-s).

In every case the error message is:

`Cannot open include file: 'SFML/Graphics/Image.hpp': No such file or directory`

My aim is that the cmake will compile SFML for other people so they won't have to be bothered about it.

Answer (score 0):

Static/shared aspects of SFML libraries during the **build** is controlled by `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` option:

```
# Build SFML libraries as static ones
set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS OFF)

FetchContent_MakeAvailable(sfml)

#linking libraries
target_link_libraries(ProgramName sfml-graphics sfml-window sfml-system ...)
```

This option is noted in the [SFML documentation](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.6/compile-with-cmake.php).

The option `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` is not SFML-specific: it is honored by CMake itself ([CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/BUILD_SHARED_LIBS.html)) and affects on common `add_library` calls.

---

The option `SFML_STATIC_LIBRARIES` which you have tried to use is for `find_package(SFML)` - another way of including SFML library into the project.
That way implies that SFML is already installed.

Comment: for me it has no effect, there are still needed .dll files...

Comment: Just checked - the option `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` correctly choose shared/static aspects of SFML on Linux. Behavior on Windows shouldn't be different. What exact `.dll`s are required when you run your application?